# parsing and editing html in php

Tags: php, html, parsing

Can anybody tell me how to parse and edit HTML in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: How you can know that from the question as it stands is beyond me. Looks useful, but I'm not sure that is what he's after.

Comment: Just discovered PHP Simple HTML DOM a fews days ago in a Stack Overflow discussion, and viewed it in my bookmarks like five minuts before reading this question. I'm just lucky :-p

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about this either, thx p4bl0 (Incidently negative votes can also help: the question title looked OK, but the neg votes made me curious - and lo & behold: I learned something!)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the question... Maybe because English is not my natural language?

Comment: It isn't mine neither, that's another way to explain that i understood :-D